# How is "No such file or directory" getting added to my PATH variable?

Tags: command-line, login, environment-variables, bashrc

Today I noticed that my path has an entry  `No such file or directory` at the end, which causing other problems.

My path looks like this: `/home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory`

I can't figure out what's adding it, and would like to know how to troubleshoot it.

I checked `.bashrc` and didn't notice any problems. The `.bashrc` adds anaconda and Ruby as expected.

Based on [this great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash) on how the PATH is set, I checked my `~/.profile` file.  The profile script just runs .bashrc, and adds `$HOME/bin` and `$HOME/.local/bin` to the path. Those paths are only added if they exist, and they do.

I read what I could understand of `man login`. This led me to check `/etc/login.defs`, but that looked very vanilla. I don't have any of the other files mentioned in the login help.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot where this is happening?

### EDIT: Jan 11, 2021

Based on the comments I edited the question to say that I had checked `~.profile`.

I also made a very simple version of `~.bashrc`, rebooted, and ran bash with the debug commands. The `PATH` is still corrupted.

```
geneorama@computer:~$ bash -x ~/.bashrc
+ HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
+ shopt -s histappend
+ HISTSIZE=9999999
+ HISTFILESIZE=999999999
+ shopt -s checkwinsize
geneorama@computer:~$ $PATH
bash: /home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

### EDIT: Jan 11, 2021 (second edit today)

I also noticed that I can't fix the error by manually setting the path or by logging in as root. I tried using `export` and setting the path using a quoted string (I don't know if it matters or the best way).

```
geneorama@computer:~$ $PATH
bash: /home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
geneorama@computer:~$ PATH="/home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
geneorama@computer:~$ $PATH
bash: /home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
geneorama@computer:~$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for geneorama: 
root@ativ4-v18:~# $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
root@ativ4-v18:~# logout
geneorama@computer:~$ export PATH=/home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
geneorama@computer:~$ $PATH
bash: /home/geneorama/gems/bin:/home/geneorama/anaconda3/bin:/home/geneorama/.local/bin:/home/geneorama/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
```

Also looked in `/etc/environment/` and `/etc/environment.d/`.  The first was empty and the second had two files `90atk-adaptor.conf` and `90qt-a11y.conf`, but they do not seem to be affecting the path.

### EDIT: Jan 11, 2021 (third edit today)

Even when I manually set my path to be just `/sbin` and `/bin` I get the error. At this point I don't understand if the error message is actually on my path or printing along with the path.

```
geneorama@computer:~$ export PATH=/sbin:/bin
geneorama@computer:~$ $PATH
bash: /sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
```

### EDIT: Jan 12, 2021

Originally I was getting an error in Jekyll.  Some sites said that my error was caused by spaces in `$PATH`. When I (improperly) printed my `$PATH` I thought that something was trying to add a path that I had deleted. I thought that I had uninstalled something improperly.

The spaces being printed were part of an error message, not part of the `$PATH`.

Apparently Jekyll was corrupted, and the solution was to `apt remove` it and then reinstall it.

Along the way I learned that the path variable is modified in many non-obvious ways. **The answer to my question was essentially "print your $PATH correctly".**

One day someone may ask "how to I debug / profile edits to my $PATH?", and someone may mark it as a duplicate. It's not a duplicate of this question. This question turned out to be "how do I print $PATH".

Comment: Look in your .profile for PATH modifications.

Comment: Debug via `bash -x ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @ubfan1 I edited my question. I had checked the .profile, but I typed the wrong filename. Had some distractions while trying to write the question.

Comment: @waltinator thank you. I followed your suggestion and edited my question.

Comment: If you're going to downvote the question, please let me know why. I did my best to understand the issue and document it. Although it turned out to be a confusing error message resulting from an improper echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't with your `PATH`, it's with how you're trying to display it. The first thing in a command line is the command you're running. If you just type `$PATH`, the shell will try to run your `PATH` as a command, and it's not a command -- it's a colon-delimited list of directories to look for commands in. Since there's no actual command by that name, you get an error. (And since it's looking for an executable *file* corresponding to that command, the error you get is "No such file or directory").

To display the value of a shell varible like `PATH` correctly, use e.g. `echo "$PATH"` (or if it might contain backslashes/escapes, use `printf '%s\n' "$PATH"` instead). You can sometimes omit the double-quotes around variable references, but not always, so it's safer to just get in the habit of double-quoting variable references. And I mean always, not just in `echo` commands. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) for more explanation.

For `PATH` specifically, it's often easier to see it if it's broken up into separate directories; you can use the `tr` command to turn the colon delimiters into newlines. Compare these two examples:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

$ echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have accepted your answer and added notes to my question, which is much too verbose. In following the Stack Exchange rules I think we often end up with questions that are overly verbose, but that meta conversation is beyond the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

How are you displaying the $PATH?  Use

```
echo $PATH
```

and you should not see the error message.
If you had been using something like

```
ls $PATH
```

You get such an error appended at the end.

There is nothing wrong with your PATH.  But the string of directories is not a file, and if you treat it like one (trying to execute it by just typing $PATH or trying to look at it with ls $PATH, you will get the error that it is not a file.

Comment: Yes, echo does not show the error, but ls $PATH does. I was typing $PATH to view the path. Also, thank you for your comments.

Comment: The problem is that certain Ruby commands won't run if $PATH has spaces.  This was working last week, but now it's not. I didn't manually edit my path or change my .bashrc.  All I've done was run some Ruby / Jekyll / Bundler commands.

Comment: @geneorama The first thing in a command line is the command you're running. If you just type `$PATH`, the shell will try to run your `PATH` as a command, and it's not a command -- it's a colon-delimited list of directories to look for commands *in*. Since there's no actual command by that name, you get an error. You need to use an actual command, like `echo`. BTW, you should also quote variable names: `echo "$PATH"` instead of just `echo $PATH` (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)).

Comment: @GordonDavisson This should be the answer, not just a comment. I didn't think that `$PATH` would run as a command... normally you need to put `.` in front of something for it to be a command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson also that's a great reference on the quoting. I also appreciate the linked answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary (although it's frustrating that there are so many exceptions and gotchas. Ten years in and I still feel like I'm a noob in linux)

Comment: @geneorama IMO it's much easier to just get in the habit of double-quoting variable references than it is to try to remember where it's safe to leave them off. There are a few places where you *need* to leave them off, but that's a much shorter list and easier to remember.